# Why does resonance cause unique behavior of S-param in two-port system?

Tags: resonance, via

In a two-port system where a square signal passes through a via we can get a HIGH Q resonance structure which could ruin our S21.

I know that resonance is a standing half-wave pattern, so what what causes S21 to plunge?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> *what what causes S21 to plunge?*

S21 is the ratio of power leaving port 2 relative to the power into port 1 so, if S21 plunges, the (effective) input impedance must also plunge in order to have real power entering port 1. So, in this respect you can't really model the via like a parallel tuned circuit because it wouldn't alter S21 at all (output power ratio to input power would be the same but, power input would be very small.

However, thinking of the via as a parallel tuned circuit is convenient for explaining the loss of power reaching the output port. But, you also have to consider the via as a short length of unmatched transmission line. This creates an input impedance to signal source related to the reflected power at the via and, interfere with the S21 measurement.

Comment: Hello Andy, can i think  that the resonator causes  the signal to be trapped in the medium going back and forth and not reaching the destination? thanks.

Comment: You can but it's more standard to think of it as a blocking impedance. But, a blocking impedance isn't sufficient to explain a plunging S21 hence, we need to think of the via as creating a transmission line discontinuity also.

Comment: Hello Andy, Yes I understand the VIA is a discontinuity, but in resonance the energy is stuck in the middle so its not absorbed in none of the ports straight away.so with using the discontinuity point could you please explain how  that the energy is stuck in the middle with an example so i could simulate? Thanks.

Comment: It isn't sufficient to regard it this way as I have pointed out in my previous comment and my answer.

Comment: Hello Andy ,i'll be glad if there is some transmission line example i would see your good explanantion.

Comment: @Josh23 what are your knowledge levels on transmission lines? Do you understand reflection coefficient and how reflections can appear to change input impedances? Have you studied the quarter wave impedance transformer?

Comment: Hello Andy ,yes i did, i just want a simple example of a two port system where i could calculate the reflection coefficients and see on the mathematical level why the energy is locked in the middle during resonance.Thanks.